# dynamically apply title of html document into the title fields of images

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic-data

Good day. 
I am wondering is there any short script to apply the actual page title into the image title? So if I have this page title in my head section:

```
<head>
    <title>Dogs</title>
</head>
```

and these images:

```
<a class="sth" href="#" title="PROBLEM"><img src="img01.jpg" alt="sth"/></a>
<a class="sth" href="#" title="PROBLEM"><img src="img02.jpg" alt="sth"/></a>
<a class="sth" href="#" title="PROBLEM"><img src="img03.jpg" alt="sth"/></a>
```

I want to dynamically apply the title where it says "PROBLEM" from the page title. What is the easiest way of doing this? Does it need to be in php or can it be in javascript?

I just want "Dogs" to go in the place where "PROBLEM" is at the moment if you know what I mean. So probably "PROBLEM" needs to be replaced by a simple script. The document must remain a html by the way.

Comment: you can do it using javascript itself

Comment: its not image title, its anchor tag title. you can do it using jQuery `var txt=$('title').text(); $('a').attr('attr',txt) ` . Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var title = document.title;
$('.sth').attr('title',title);
```

Edit, but I don't really see the point of doing this. The title of the site has little to do with the images, if it's added to all of them, what is the point anyways?

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski - For all of them.

Comment: :) great, will check now and accept your answer, much appreciated :)

Comment: it's for the gallery, I will be able to change the title of the page only, if there will be 100 of images I won't be able to edit this part later unfortuantely. so your script will do this job

Answer (score 2):

Why couldn't you do this in PHP?

**PHP**

```
$title = "Dogs";
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="sth" href="#" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"><img src="img01.jpg" alt="sth"/></a>
<a class="sth" href="#" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"><img src="img02.jpg" alt="sth"/></a>
<a class="sth" href="#" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"><img src="img03.jpg" alt="sth"/></a>
```

So set a var in PHP, and echo it where you want it to be shown.
PHP would be best so it renders as it should right from the start of the page load (Also so search engines can crawl it). You can do it via javascript, but this may cause dodgy results with SEO.

*If you can*, **always** do stuff like this in PHP (Or whatever server side language you code in), unless you absolutely have no other choice to use javascript.

Comment: Things like this should always be done on the server unless `absolutely necessary`, Using javascript for this will probably cause you more problems in the long run. (The Javascript is more of a `hacky` solution, but if its the only way to get it done, do it... But where possible, try and do it `properly` in `PHP` before the page renders)

Comment: Ya i agree on that, but why would anyone want to hack the js script which is merely changing the title of the anchor tag. anyway with your approach as well, i dont find any extra security concern. after all its just the title of the anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

in your head part use

```
<?php
$title_set = "Dogs";
echo "<title>$title_set</t?>itle>";
?>
```

Every where where you have images use this

```
<a class="sth" href="#" title="
<?php
echo $title_set;
?>
"><img src="img01.jpg" alt="sth"/></a>
```

Please remember to change $title_set for each page, or it will be set for every page.